# Trying to get property 'cover_image' of non-object (View: C:\Users\BWB\Documents\Laravel\asperablogs\resources\views\blogs\blogs.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm making a blog website and I'm implementing tags. I keep getting the error in the title and not sure what I'm supposed to do. I've looked through similar questions here but they look different from how i've done it. Im using pivot tables for the the tags.  When I did it with the posts only it worked well and displayed everything
here is the index method from my posts controller.

```
public function index()
{
   $posts = Post::all()->sortByDesc('created_at');
   return view('blogs.blogs', compact('posts'));
}
```

here is the index method from my tag controller.

```
public function index(Tag $tag){
    $posts = $tag->posts();
    return view('blogs.blogs')->with('posts',$posts);
}
```

Here is how I'm outputting it in the view

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="well row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img style="width: 100%" src="/storage/cover_images/{{$post->cover_image}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3> <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h3>
            <h3>{{$post->created_at}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This is my tags model

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error**

Your error comes from the fact that the variable `$post` within your foreach loop has returned as a non-object.

---

**Probable Cause**

That `$posts` is not being returned as a collection but rather a query builder instance

```
$posts = $tag->posts();
```

If you have built an eloquent relationship between a `Tag` model and a `Post` model, when you access this as a method (i.e. `$tag->posts()`) you will get an eloquent query builder instance. If you access this as a property (i.e. `$tag->posts`), it will return an eloquent collection.

---

**Suggestion**

Try passing the posts to the view as a collection

```
public function index(Tag $tag) {
    return view('blogs.blogs', [
        'posts' => $tag->posts
    ]);
}
```

And try using a `@forelse` loop to catch the instances where you have no posts

```
@forelse ($posts as $post)

@empty

@endforelse
```